# How to do a break-sort using Mustache.js?

Tags: handlebars.js

newbie to Mustache here

I would like to create a table that uses one part of the template if the value of a field changes from one row to the next.

With data like the following *(sorted at source by 'group')*:

```
0: {
    'group': 'stars',
    'name': 'George',
    'rating': '5'
    }
1: {
    'group': 'stars',
    'name': 'Tom',
    'rating': '3'
    }
2: {
    'group': 'singers',
    'name': 'Tanya',
    'rating': '5'
    }
3: {
    'group': 'singers',
    'name': 'Fred',
    'rating': '4'
    }
```

Would produce:

```
+----------------------+
|     NAME    | Rating |
+----------------------+
|         stars        |
+----------------------+
| George      |   5    |
+----------------------+
| Tom         |   3    |
+----------------------+
|        singers       |
+----------------------+
| Tanya       |   5    |
+----------------------+
| Fred        |   4    |
+----------------------+
```

Is there a way/function in Mustache.js to do this? Something like an if/else with a test for a change in a variable's value from one row to the next?

Comment: Why not just create a new object with the groups as indexes? ie. `{ stars: [], singers: [] }`.

Comment: @76484 Can you nest the groups in the template?

Comment: Here is what I had in mind: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/sxkaqz5d/